# BizTalk Pipeline Component custom UI

Tags: user-interface, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I am working on a pipeline component in BizTalk. The component is ready and working fine.

For the component I want to change the UI as shown in the BizTalk admin console. I am aware of IComponentUI interface responsible for UI of pipeline components.

I want to introduce an ellipsis button or text area in one of the property of the pipeline component in BizTalk admin console.

Is it possible with existing framework or I need to implement any COM interface for that.

Any help would be much appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `IComponentUI` interface is only used by Visual Studio at design time.  It's not used by the admin console at all.  It's possible to develop restrictions around it and probably even put the ellipses you're looking for in there with a custom textbox for it, but that would only ever show up in the Visual Studio properties window, *not the Admin Console*.  In that area you're pretty much relegated to having either the simple text entry box or having a boolean dropdown box (if the property is a bool).

You have a bit more flexibility if you're developing a custom adapter as opposed to a custom pipeline - take a look at how it's done in the [Scheduled Task Adapter](https://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/) for example, where custom dialogs are created for setting various adapter properties.

If you really need this for a pipeline component, I'd suggest having the pipeline pull its actual properties from somewhere else **that's centrally accessible** (because your pipeline might be used in a multi-server environment, and you would likely want the configuration to be consistent across servers for the same receive location/send port) such as a database or SSO, and creating your configuration UI on top of that as a separate application.  Just be aware that it might be confusing to BizTalk admins who might expect to see the relevant properties in that properties window, and might be confused as to where they're actually supposed to configure something.

Comment: But Pipeline Component properties are already centrally stored in the database.

Comment: Yes, of course - attempting to modify them in the BizTalk databases directly is a bad idea though, and putting UI constraints/assistants around how they're entered at runtime isn't possible in the admin console.  My suggestion is that if this is really needed or desired, it'd require some other method for controlling them, that would perhaps still be driven by a regular pipeline property (e.g. SSO App name as a pipeline property).